# Как вернуть удаленную ветку?

Tags: git

История такая, что ветка была удалена в origin(remote) еще несколько месяцев назад. Была замержена в основную и благополучно удалена, после нее уже 100500 коммитов было и других мерджей, так что найти где она была замержена не представляется возможным. Но вдруг понадобилось знать где она была.

Насколько я знаю уже ничего сделать нельзя, но решил вот задать вопрос, может есть все же возможность вернуть ее.

Comment: Что такое "ветка с origin"? Может ее снова оттуда выкачать? Или она была удалена в origin репозитории? А вообще попробуйте mercurial, в нем полноценные ветки.

Comment: @user7860670 да в origin ветка была удалена

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найти мерж-коммит сравнительно легко при условии, что сообщение
о мерже не меняли со стандартного:

```sh
git log --merges --grep="Merge branch 'feature/ABC-123' into master"
```

После этого просто переходите на один из родителей и пересоздаёте
ветку.

Comment: это нужно знать точное название ветки... А можно найти все мерджи с мастером? Как то так `git log --merges --grep="Merge brach ... into master`?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko  `git log --merges master`.